# show share this link in drupal

Tags: drupal

I would like to show share this widget in all my webpages in my drupal site right below the title.

Can you tell me which file i should edit?

I tried the addthis module. no Luck :(

it gives javascript error when implemented.

-Vivek

Comment: Er... what widget? What Drupal theme? What JavaScript error?

Comment: garland theme, addthis module, unterminated string

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Add to Any](http://drupalmodules.com/module/add-to-any-sharebookmark-button) module

Answer (score 0):

AddThis module works fine. The latest version has never thrown a js error for me, it could be something else on your website.